# Android ObjectAnimation only started once

Tags: android, animation, android-3.0-honeycomb

I use the ObjectAnimator API (android.animation.ObjectAnimator) to animate a button once it's clicked (v is the Button):

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotationY", 360f);
animator.setDuration(5000);
animator.start();
```

When I test this on the emulator, it works for the first click (button rotates). But when I click the button again (the fragment is not destroyed etc. after the first click), I don't see any animation on the emulator (the emulator isn't the fastest, but with 5 seconds I should see something).

Do I need to destroy/close something after the first animation or what am I missing?
Does anyone have a hint or can reproduce this?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: This code is inside your Button event?

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos yes it is inside the onClick method of the assigned OnClickListener. I can see in the debugger that the code is actually run. Not sure what the framework does though, as it says the animation is not run immediately (but in another thread I think).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second time you will try to animate from 360.0f to 360.0f. Change your call to ofFloat() to:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360.0f)
```

Answer (score 9):

To elaborate on Romain's answer, the result of the single-value factory constructor is animation that will run from whatever the current value is to the value specified in the parameters. In your case, the object had a value of 0 to begin with an animated (the first time) to a value of 360. The second time it ran, it animated from the current value (360) to the specified value (360). Not much of an animation.

The fix is as above: hard-code both the start and end values for the animator. Alternatively, you can reset the value back to 0 when the animation finishes by implementing the AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd method and resetting it when the animation finishes:

```
    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            v.setRotationY(0);
        }
    });
```