# Creating a 3D flip animation in Android using XML

Tags: android, xml, animation, 3d

I have created a 3D flip of a view using [this android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html) 
However, I have done it programmatically and I would like to do it all in xml, if possible.  I am not talking about simply shrinking a view to the middle and then back out, but an actual 3D flip.

Is this possible via xml?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is the answer, though it only works with 3.0 and above.

1) Create a new resources folder called "animator".

2) Create a new .xml file which I will call "flipping".  Use the following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:valueFrom="0" android:valueTo="360" android:propertyName="rotationY" >
</objectAnimator>
```

No, the objectAnimator tags do not start with an uppercase "O".

3) Start the animation with the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mContext, R.animator.flipping); 
anim.setTarget(A View Object reference goes here i.e. ImageView);
anim.setDuration(3000);
anim.start();
```

I got all this from [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html).

Comment: @RAS Thanks for the link to the library. :)  Maybe next time it could go in the comments rather than editing my answer?  I don't know anything about this library so to have it attributed to me is not quite correct.  Thanks for your input though!

Comment: I understand your point that nobody likes someone editing his/her post without his/her permission. But this answer is not edited by me. It is edited by someone else, I just approved it & solved a grammar mistake done by that person who edited your answer. If you want to check it out, click on the Date/time shown beside "edited", above my name & logo. You can see the full revision history there.

Comment: To use this code below 3.0 use the following lib: https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids.  Contributed by user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1117511/loks

Comment: Its work but works once for a view, only one time it was flip , second time for the same view its not work

Comment: @KrunalShah I ran into the same issue :)  This fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5317467/269876

Comment: @KrunalShah Actually, just add android:valueFrom="0" to the objectAnimator declaration to fix the problem.

Comment: This results in a rather naive flip, some scaling should be implemented to make it more visually appealing.

Comment: A flip requires two views, one to hide and one to show. How did this answer, which only flips one view, get so many upvotes??

Answer (score 30):

Since the answers to this question are fairly dated, here is a more modern solution relying on ValueAnimators.
This solution implements a true, visually appealing 3D-flip, because it not just flips the view, but also scales it while it is flipping (this is how Apple does it).

First we set up the ValueAnimator:

```
mFlipAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
mFlipAnimator.addUpdateListener(new FlipListener(frontView, backView));
```

And the corresponding update listener:

```
public class FlipListener implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

    private final View mFrontView;
    private final View mBackView;
    private boolean mFlipped;

    public FlipListener(final View front, final View back) {
        this.mFrontView = front;
        this.mBackView = back;
        this.mBackView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(final ValueAnimator animation) {
        final float value = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
        final float scaleValue = 0.625f + (1.5f * (value - 0.5f) * (value - 0.5f));

        if(value <= 0.5f){
            this.mFrontView.setRotationY(180 * value);
            this.mFrontView.setScaleX(scaleValue);
            this.mFrontView.setScaleY(scaleValue);
            if(mFlipped){
                setStateFlipped(false);
            }
        } else {
            this.mBackView.setRotationY(-180 * (1f- value));
            this.mBackView.setScaleX(scaleValue);
            this.mBackView.setScaleY(scaleValue);
            if(!mFlipped){
                setStateFlipped(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setStateFlipped(boolean flipped) {
        mFlipped = flipped;
        this.mFrontView.setVisibility(flipped ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        this.mBackView.setVisibility(flipped ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**That's it!**

After this setup you can flip the views by calling

```
mFlipAnimator.start();
```

and reverse the flip by calling

```
mFlipAnimator.reverse();
```

If you want to check if the view is flipped, implement and call this function:

```
private boolean isFlipped() {
    return mFlipAnimator.getAnimatedFraction() == 1;
}
```

You can also check if the view is currently flipping by implementing this method:

```
private boolean isFlipping() {
    final float currentValue = mFlipAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
    return (currentValue < 1 && currentValue > 0);
}
```

You can combine the above functions to implement a nice function to toggle the flip, depending on if it is flipped or not:

```
private void toggleFlip() {
    if(isFlipped()){
        mFlipAnimator.reverse();
    } else {
        mFlipAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

That's it! Simple and easy. Enjoy!

Comment: I am trying to translate your algorithm into an XML tween animation. I can't figure out how to set properly the pivotX and pivotY properties: do you have any idea?

Comment: @AntonioSesto Sorry, I mostly animate without xml because I find animating in code more versatile. I think setting the pivot in xml will be hard, since you don't know the views dimensions. Maybe you can set it as percentage though, have you tried setting the pivot to something like 50%p?

Comment: @A.Steenbergen How can I change the duration?

Comment: mFlipAnimator.setDuration(duration)

Comment: This works flawlessly!! Thank you for posting this answer!! Appreciate the help! +1 from me

Comment: It took me hours to find an answer that didn't involve fragments, animated both views and not just one, was 3d, and actually worked for the forward and reverse flips. This is it, thanks!!

Comment: Really amazing, I made the implementation in kotlin using the rotation in a Relative Layout, it worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I have created a simple program for creating flip of view like :

[image]

In Activity you have to create this method, for adding flip_rotation in view.

```
private void applyRotation(View view) 
{
    final Flip3dAnimation rotation = new Flip3dAnimation(view);
    rotation.applyPropertiesInRotation();
    view.startAnimation(rotation);
}
```

for this, you have to copy main class used to provide flip_rotation.

```
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class Flip3dAnimation extends Animation {
    private final float mFromDegrees;
    private final float mToDegrees;
    private final float mCenterX;
    private final float mCenterY;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public Flip3dAnimation(View view) {
        mFromDegrees = 0;
        mToDegrees = 720;
        mCenterX = view.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        mCenterY = view.getHeight() / 2.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
            int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        mCamera = new Camera();
    }

    public void applyPropertiesInRotation()
    {
        this.setDuration(2000);
        this.setFillAfter(true);
        this.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
        float degrees = fromDegrees
                + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

        final float centerX = mCenterX;
        final float centerY = mCenterY;
        final Camera camera = mCamera;

        final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

        camera.save();

        Log.e("Degree",""+degrees) ;
        Log.e("centerX",""+centerX) ;
        Log.e("centerY",""+centerY) ;

        camera.rotateY(degrees);

        camera.getMatrix(matrix);
        camera.restore();

        matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    }

}
```

Comment: This is nice, but it would be better to not rely on custom animation functions, but ObjectAnimators instead. The reason is better support and reversability.

Comment: @Tushar Pandey :- mindblowing.. what a answer.. grt dude

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial or the link by om252345 don't produce believable 3D flips. A simple rotation on the y-axis isn't what's done in iOS. The zoom effect is also needed to create that nice flip feel. For that, take a look at [this example](https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition.).
There is also a video [here](http://youtu.be/52mXHqX9f3Y).

Comment: I realize the question is on how to make the y-axis rotation in the android.com example using xml. But I figured maybe you are interested in this too.

Answer (score 5):

One of the better solution to flip the image with out use of the resource animation , is as follow:-

```
  ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(YOUR_IMAGEVIEW, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);  // HERE 360 IS THE ANGLE OF ROTATE, YOU CAN USE 90, 180 IN PLACE OF IT,  ACCORDING TO YOURS REQUIREMENT 

  animation.setDuration(500); // HERE 500 IS THE DURATION OF THE ANIMATION, YOU CAN INCREASE OR DECREASE ACCORDING TO YOURS REQUIREMENT
  animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
  animation.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The simplest way to do it is using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html)

   ```
   mImageView.animate().rotationY(360f);
   ```

   Using the fluent interface you can build more complex and exciting animation.
   E.g. you can enable hardware acceleration just call withLayer() method(API 16). More [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html)
2. If you want to figure out how to create 3d flick animation, please follow [here](http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/android-flipa-card-animation-exlpained/) and [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/)
3. I implemended my own solution only for a research. It includes: cancelation, accelleration, support API >= 15 and is based on [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).
   The entire animation includes 4 parts, 2 for each side. 
   Every objectAnimator has a listener that defines current animation index and represents an image in the onAnimationStart and current play time value in the onAnimationCancel.
   It looks like

   ```
   mQuarterAnim1.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
           mQuarterCurrentAnimStartIndex = QUARTER_ANIM_INDEX_1;
           mImageView.setImageResource(mResIdFrontCard);
       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
           mQuarterCurrentAnimPlayTime = ((ObjectAnimator) animation).getCurrentPlayTime();
       }
   });
   ```

   For start set call

   ```
   mAnimatorSet.play(mQuarterAnim1).before(mQuarterAnim2)
   ```

   If AnimatorSet was canceled we can calculate delta and run the reverse animation relying on the current index animation and the current play time value.

   ```
   long degreeDelta = mQuarterCurrentAnimPlayTime * QUARTER_ROTATE / QUARTER_ANIM_DURATION;

   if (mQuarterCurrentAnimStartIndex == QUARTER_ANIM_INDEX_1) {
       mQuarterAnim4.setFloatValues(degreeDelta, QUARTER_FROM_1);
       mQuarterAnim4.setDuration(mQuarterCurrentAnimPlayTime);

       mAnimatorSet.play(mQuarterAnim4);
   }
   ```

A full code snippet you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/yoalex5/3b9f69e90f35a04ce2da44fc304020da)

Comment: Nice one  explation @yoAlex5 +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Just put the view which you're going to animate it in place of viewToFlip.

```
ObjectAnimator flip = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToFlip, "rotationY", 0f, 360f); // or rotationX
flip.setDuration(2000); // 2 seconds
flip.start();
```

Comment: I'm revising your answer as poor quality answer, you should add an explanation to your code...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to A. Steenbergen's great answer.  When flipping the same view (updating a `TextView` for example) I removed the `View.Visibility` change in the constructor in order to keep the transition smoother.

```
public FlipListener(final View front, final View back) {
    this.mFrontView = front;
    this.mBackView = back;
}
```