# Making my Custom Animation available as android Tag

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

I have created a custom 3D rotation animation extending the Animation Class . Not it is quite easy for me to set it as animation of any view . But I am stuck with setting it as Animation for Dialog Window as it onlt takes an int Resource ID . Is there any way for setting an Animation Object as its animation ? or can I make my custom animation available as xml tag ?

```
  myDialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(resId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 3D animation in xml instead (analogical to a 2d animation) and pass it's resource to your view. There are plenty of examples, here are two link which seem to be useful for your goal:

[Creating a 3D flip animation in Android using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785649/creating-a-3d-flip-animation-in-android-using-xml)

[Android rotate animation between two activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853997/android-rotate-animation-between-two-activity)