# Android animation working with XML

Tags: android

i want to use Flip and 3d animation for one view either Image view or anything else,but that animation purely based upon the XML Based animation,anyone known about this help me thanks in advance..

Comment: did u tried somthing...

Comment: why does it need to be xml only?

Comment: perhaps this might help http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Comment: because i dont want to type more code to create that animation, i want to do in a simplest way so thats why i want.......

Comment: @upenpat thanks for ur idea and help, help me for the 3d rotate animation also thanks in advance

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785649/creating-a-3d-flip-animation-in-android-using-xml and here also https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/

Comment: @upenpat thank you for your help i want 3d rotation it will helpfull or not or you have anthing apart from this this help me thanks in andvance

Comment: i wanna another help friends, if some one known about this help me thanks in advance I connected my HDMI monitor with Android TV box(both device not having sensor).I need to change screen orientation of HDMI display while set my monitor position to vertical from Horizontal.(But i was done programmatically change layout orientation.In that,videoview's orientation not changed and also video not played).